# MATLAB: rotate 3-D plot about Z-axis with mouse scroll wheel

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

What is the simplest command-line method to enable rotating a 3D plot (around the Z-axis) with the mouse scroll-wheel?  Solutions that are independent of OS are preferred.

Solutions that can control the 'step' for each rotation shall enter the 'double-bonus' round.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is the following command :

```
rotate3d on
```